# charAt :error java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, etl, talend

I am trying to use talend to check if the 4th character = 4 then I conversion S _ if not we keep the value
the input file is an Excel file
who can help me

```
 row1.B.charAt(4) == '4'? StringHandling.CHANGE(StringHandling.LEFT(row1.B,9) ,"_","S"):row1.B
```

I have this error

```
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tMap_1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at projectname.test_0_1.test.tFileInputExcel_2Process(test.java:1140)
    at projectname.test_0_1.test.runJobInTOS(test.java:1672)
    at projectname.test_0_1.test.main(test.java:1540)
```

Comment: check your `row1` and `row1.B`, if they are null.

Comment: if I change the code  StringHandling.CHANGE(StringHandling.LEFT(row1.B,9) ,"_","S") it works  but if i add row1.B.charAt(4) == '4' dosen't works :(

Answer (score 4):

Either `row1` or `row1.B` (use proper caps! attributes begin with lower case) are `null`

UPDATE: Regardint the comment to your question, then `row1.B` is null. Check for it and either control it in the condition `((row1.B != null) && (....))` or `((row1.B == null) || (...))` or (more probably) check your logic to assign a proper value to it.

Comment: if I change the code StringHandling.CHANGE(StringHandling.LEFT(row1.B,9) ,"_","S") it works but if i add row1.B.charAt(4) == '4' dosen't works :(

Answer (score 0):

A null pointer exception is caused when you dereference a variable that is pointing to null.

In you case either `row1` or `row1.B` are `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this is to write a user routine and then just call the function from tMap on the row input.
E.g. userFunction(row1.B)

Make the function output whatever string manipulation you need.
This also allows you to handle the case where the B cell in Excel is null. You can't do that in a one liner in tMap.